# Why is my build pipeline suddenly failing with code analysis errors?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, code-analysis

I have a project that was using the VS 2017 agent pool in Azure devops and building without issues. In order to use features from newer versions of C#, this has been updated to the `windows-2019` Agent specification. Suddenly, the build step fails with errors following the `Running Code Analysis` line. Looking at the errors in the default ruleset in Visual Studio, they are all marked as warnings rather than errors so shouldn't be causing the build to fail

There are too many issues to fix right now, as this is an older project. Apart from creating a custom ruleset that disables all of these rules, is there a way to keep the new features of `Windows-2019` without having code analysis fail the build?

In answer to the comment question, this is not a yaml pipeline, but done in the legacy UI

Comment: Is it a yaml pipeline?

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell see edit. It's not yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue with Visual Studio 16.8. Here is the [ticket](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2124) with the same issue on github.

You can try workarounds provided by this [link](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/After-168-update-getting-lot-of-code-an/1251574?preview=true#T-N1255914):

1. Please set ‘`CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors`’ property to false if
   you prefer CA warnings not to be treated as errors:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview#treat-warnings-as-errors
2. If you are running legacy binary FxCop: ‘RunCodeAnalysis’ property
   is used for executing deprecated binary FxCop based CodeAnalysis.
   Please refer to
   https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019#does-the-runcodeanalysis-msbuild-project-property-run-analyzers.
   The default value for the property is false, so you should consider
   just removing this property from your project file OR setting it
   explicitly to false. Please consider migrating from legacy
   CodeAnalysis to source based CodeAnalysis:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/migrate-from-legacy-analysis-to-fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2019